# Increment Item Count when Value Hits 50

Tags: javascript

I have a configurable product that allows a user to specify a quantity. The item is made on a sheet with multiple items on it (50) and if the user specifies:

```
0-50 = 1 sheet
51-100 = 2 sheets
101-150 = 3 sheets
```

And so on until about 700 units. Currently I am doing this:

```
sheetCount = quantity / 50; 
if (sheetCount == 0) {
    sheetCount = 1; 
}
  if (pixelcounts[key] < 50) {
                sheetcount = 1; 
            } else if (pixelcounts[key] > 50 && pixelcounts[key] < 100) {
                sheetcount = 2; 
            } else if (pixelcounts[key] >= 100 && pixelcounts[key] < 150) {
                       sheetcount = 3; 
            } else if (pixelcounts[key] >= 150 && pixelcounts[key] < 200) {
                sheetcount = 4; 
            } else if (pixelcounts[key] >= 200).......
```

Is there an easier way to loop through this?

Comment: "And then specifying each individual if statement for the number ranges. Is there an easier way to loop through this?" I didn't get that. Can you show some output?

Comment: `sheetCount = Math.ceil(quantity / 50);` ?

Comment: `sheetCount = Math.floor((quantity - 1) / 50) + 1`

Comment: Perfect - Evilzebra you got it for me and I had already made the edit to the code that mellamokb suggested. Thanks everyone!!

Comment: Note that your code says 0-**49** = 1 sheet, 51-**99** = 2 sheets, **100**-**149** = 3 sheets, etc. which is different than what you posted. Off-by-one errors are extremely common in software and it's important to be exact.

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you! Please 'answer' the post and I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by what your code sample says (which is different than your example), the following should work:

```
sheetCount = Math.floor(pixelcounts[key] / 50) + 1;
```

Comment: Was a bug. I had quickly added the example statements to explain what I was trying to do to the first commenter.

Answer (score 2):

`sheetCount = Math.ceil( quantity / 50 );`